# Why is my bevel modifier not applying to one of my meshes?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I'm following Blender Guru's sofa tutorial (evidently not well), I've come to the part where I copy of the bevel and mirror modifiers to the frame (exact bit [here](https://youtu.be/BcWM9PBCVHw?t=1284)). However, the U frame at the back doesn't seem to copy or show the bevel despite it saying it's applied.

Working files is here if it helps: https://we.tl/t-gjJ2YeoSr2

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices which creates zero area faces. This stops the bevel working as intended as it clamps the bevel to zero. Select all the vertices and merge by distance with Mesh > Merge > By Distance or press <kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the merge menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have some overlapping vertex issue on the front right bottom part of your mesh.

[image]

You just have to merge vertices by selecting your problem mesh in edit mode, then pressing "M" key and then selecting "Merge by distance"
It should be fixed

[image]